# Computing a lower bound for partition function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, number-theory

Let $$F(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p(n)x^n=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{1-x^n}$$ be the generating function for the partitions. I showed that $$\log F(x) \sim \frac{\pi^2}{6(1-x)} \quad as\quad x\to 1,\quad 0<x<1$$
($\sim$ means that limit of the ratio is 1)

Using this, I got $p(n) \le e^{c_2\sqrt n}$ for some $c_2>0$. I also want to show $e^{c_1\sqrt n} \le p(n) $ also holds for some $c_1>0$. I proceed as: $$\log F(e^{-y}) \sim \frac{\pi^2}{6(1-e^{-y})} \sim \frac{\pi^2}{6y}$$ so as $y \to 0^+$, exsits $0<c<\pi^2/6$ such that $F(e^{-y})\ge e^{c/y}$. So $$\sum_{n=0}^{m}p(n)e^{-ny}\ge e^{c/y}-\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}e^{c_2\sqrt n}e^{-ny}$$ Now the hint suggest that take $y=A{\sqrt m}^{-1}$ where $A$ is a large constant, and use $p(n)$ is increasing. But I don't know how to clean the last term. What should I do?

Comment: F(x) = 1 / QPochhammer[x, x]. Could that be of any help ?

Comment: C1 is approximately $\sqrt \frac{2}{3} \pi$